# Reset Button Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a table with a search bar which will allow me to filter the data based on what I type in the search bar. The problem I have is with the reset button I created. What I want is for the search bar to be cleared and the table to return back to its original state showing all the data (NOT the filtered data)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/RichStyle.css">
    <!-- Custom Made CSS -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/toggle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery%201.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JS -->

    <!-- Slide Toggle -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $('td p').slideUp();
                    $('td h2').click(
                            function(){
                                $(this).closest('tr').find('p').slideToggle();
                            }
                    );
                }
        );

    </script>

    <!-- Search Bar -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#search').keyup(function() {
                searchTable($(this).val());
            });
        });
        function searchTable(inputVal) {
            var table = $('#searchTable');
            table.find('tr').each(function(index, row) {
                var allCells = $(row).find('td');
                if (allCells.length > 0) {
                    var found = false;
                    allCells.each(function(index, td) {
                        var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                        if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                            found = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (found == true)
                        $(row).show();
                    else
                        $(row).hide();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <title>Report Page</title>

</head>

<body>

<div>
    <p>
    <form>
    <label for="search"></label>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter Search Term" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form>
    </p>

<table id="searchTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Hours Spent</th>
        <th>Data Usage</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><h2>Luke</h2></td>
        <td><h3 id="Luke">

            <script>
                var website = ["Facebook", "Youtube"];
                document.getElementById("Luke").innerHTML = website.length;
            </script></h3><p>Facebook</p><p>Youtube</p></td>
        <td><h3>2.5h</h3><p>2h</p><p>0.5h</p></td>
        <td><h3>1.3gb</h3><p>3mb</p><p>1gb</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h2>John</h2></td>
        <td><h3 id="John">

            <script>
                var website = ["Youtube"];
                document.getElementById("John").innerHTML = website.length;
            </script></h3><p>Youtube</p></td>
        <td><h3>3h</h3><p>3h</p></td>
        <td><h3>1gb</h3><p>1gb</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h2>Peter</h2></td>
        <td><h3 id="Peter">

            <script>
                var website = ["Facebook", "Youtube"];
                document.getElementById("Peter").innerHTML = website.length;
            </script></h3><p>Facebook</p><p>Youtube</p></td>
        <td><h3>1.75h</h3><p>1.5h</p><p>0.25h</p></td>
        <td><h3>1.3gb</h3><p>3mb</p><p>1gb</p></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div>

<button onclick="window.print()">Print Report</button>
<!-- Javascript Coding - No Colours Displayed On Print Preview-->
<button>Save Report</button>
<!-- Save Button Does Not Work, Fix Needed-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the `<input type="reset"` will  only reset the inputs that are edditable and WITHIN  the form

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this so I don't quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 3):

IF you want to use the `<input type="reset" />` tag, the elements you can **reset** must be `editable`, i.e. you can type whatever you want into it, so

1. input type="text"
2. input type="password"
3. input type="email"
4. etc. . .

The above are editable.
So if what you want is that, you have no more **data** in your `table` you can use  JQuery,  here's an example using   `input reset`

```js
$(function(){ // this is === to  document.ready
  
  $("#the-table .ins").val("some value here ");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- the tags that you can enter text into can be reset if they resied within the same form that contains the  reset button -->
<form action="some url" method="post">
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /> <br />
        Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" /><br />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear form" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
</form>
<hr />
With a  table: 

<!-- so when the page loads, we use JQuery to insert so value to your table -->
<form action="some url" method="post">
  <table id="the-table">
    <tr><td><input class="ins" type="text"  /></td>
    <td><input class="ins" type="text"  /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear form" />
</form>
```

and here's an example using  jquery to clear the `table` **data**

```js
$(function(){

  $('#reset-btn').click(function(){
  
      $('table tr').remove();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>click on the table to remove data </h2>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="reset-btn">reset data</button>
```

Comment: Okay I understand now thank you! Although I'm not 100% sure how to implement that into my coding

Comment: @RichardSiaw, well your question is about "how to reset table data", so I've edited the code so that  it uses a button to reset the data, take a look

Comment: Oh I see my mistake in the question now! Haha need to change it! I'm sorry for the misunderstanding but I wanted the table to return back to the way it was at the beginning or in other words I want it to show back all the data if the reset button was clicked.

Comment: To avoid any confusion I wanted my table to work something similar to this jsfiddle table created by someone else.
http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/RgKPZ/

Answer (score 2):

@esteban rincon is right, `<input type="reset" value="Reset" />` can reset your form input but won't clear any other HTML content.

You need to clear by your self.

For example you can add id attribute in your reset button and add onClick event to clear your `searchTable` like `$('#searchTable').empty();`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/RichStyle.css">
  <!-- Custom Made CSS -->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/toggle.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery%201.4.4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- JS -->

  <!-- Slide Toggle -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
      function() {
        $('td p').slideUp();
        $('td h2').click(
          function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('p').slideToggle();
          }
        );
      }
    );
  </script>

  <!-- Search Bar -->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#search').keyup(function() {
        searchTable($(this).val());
      });
      //Add this for reset click reset your search record
      $('#resetAll').click(function() {
        $('#searchTable tbody').empty();
      });
    });

    function searchTable(inputVal) {
      var table = $('#searchTable');
      table.find('tr').each(function(index, row) {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if (allCells.length > 0) {
          var found = false;
          allCells.each(function(index, td) {
            var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
            if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
              found = true;
              return false;
            }
          });
          if (found == true)
            $(row).show();
          else
            $(row).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  </script>

  <title>Report Page</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <p>
      <form>
        <label for="search"></label>
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter Search Term" />
        <!-- add id resetAll -->
        <input id="resetAll" type="reset" value="Reset" />
      </form>
    </p>

    <table id="searchTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User ID</th>
          <th>Website</th>
          <th>Hours Spent</th>
          <th>Data Usage</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h2>Luke</h2>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3 id="Luke">

            <script>
                var website = ["Facebook", "Youtube"];
                document.getElementById("Luke").innerHTML = website.length;
            </script></h3>
            <p>Facebook</p>
            <p>Youtube</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3>2.5h</h3>
            <p>2h</p>
            <p>0.5h</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3>1.3gb</h3>
            <p>3mb</p>
            <p>1gb</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h2>John</h2>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3 id="John">

            <script>
                var website = ["Youtube"];
                document.getElementById("John").innerHTML = website.length;
            </script></h3>
            <p>Youtube</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3>3h</h3>
            <p>3h</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3>1gb</h3>
            <p>1gb</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h2>Peter</h2>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3 id="Peter">

            <script>
                var website = ["Facebook", "Youtube"];
                document.getElementById("Peter").innerHTML = website.length;
            </script></h3>
            <p>Facebook</p>
            <p>Youtube</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3>1.75h</h3>
            <p>1.5h</p>
            <p>0.25h</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3>1.3gb</h3>
            <p>3mb</p>
            <p>1gb</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <button onclick="window.print()">Print Report</button>
  <!-- Javascript Coding - No Colours Displayed On Print Preview-->
  <button>Save Report</button>
  <!-- Save Button Does Not Work, Fix Needed-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I copied that right but thatcode just removed the entire table when I click the reset button

Comment: That's not in your question.So I just remove the search result in the table. You need to change `$('#searchTable').empty();` for whatever you want to do.

Comment: Oh sorry for not being clear! I wanted the table to return back to the way it was at the beginning or in other words I want it to show back all the data if the reset button was clicked.

Comment: In the case you described, you need to define what is `the beginning of your table`? Because what we saw is the code you post and we can't imagine what will be shown after or before your search.

Comment: Basically my table looks something like this jsfiddle table (http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/RgKPZ/)
I wanted my table to work something similar to this

Comment: Oh man.....You need to clearify your question.Not use another link that I can't seen what is the relation of your question.What I can help is some codes `After you described your question clearly` but not `being a psychic`.

Comment: Okay I have reworded my questions. I'm not sure how clear it is now but I hope its more accurate now than what it was before! Really sorry for the trouble I'm causing everyone...

Comment: I've change the code that reset click function to `$('#searchTable tbody').empty()`. and it will empty the tbody's contents. you can check if this is you want.